# AG Grid Column Selection Disable

Tags: ag-grid

I am using AG-Grid and I would like to disable or hide the Column Selection option from Column Header and Columns Tool Panel.
See bellow images about what I would like to disable or hide:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to disable or hide the column selection checkboxes when the AG-Grid grid is build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sidebar:

> To display just one of the provided tool panels, set either sideBar='columns' or sideBar='filters'.

see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/side-bar/#string-configuration).

```
<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [sideBar]="'filters'"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
```

For the column menu:

> The menu will be displayed by default and will be made up of three panels. If you want to change the order or what panels are shown, or hide them, you can specify the property menuTabs in the colDef.
>
> The property menuTabs is an array of strings. The valid values are:
> 'filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab' and 'columnsMenuTab'

see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-menu/#showing-the-column-menu)

```
this.defaultColDef = {
      filter: true,
      menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab'],
    };
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&preview).